# Magento 2: How to make new billing address form shows up in popup in checkout just like new shipping address form?

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, shipping-address, billing-address

In magento 2 checkout page there will be a pop up form when we add new address instead of using current shipping address, but for billing address the new billing address form is below the dropdown, is there a way to make the new billing address form shows up in pop up just like new address form?

Comment: DID you get any solution??@jojo